# opel corsa c 1.7 DTI won't reach engine temperature

Tags: temperature, thermostat

I have a Corsa C 1.7 dti and I have a problem with it, I visited many garages to fix this problem but all of them suggested me to change the thermostat. I followed their advice, tried 4 thermostats by selecting best brands but still no success.

The engine temperature is always low (ZERO), I searched too much into Google/forums and I saw that if engine temperature stays always low it will damage your engine because now is winter and here we have minus temperatures.

I have changed temperature sensor just to make sure if sensor is working and showing me right temperature, but still zero.

If I drive it very hard core and in up roads with 5 persons and if I keep it going hard the temperature will go up to 80, but when I drive it normally the temperature will go to zero very fast.

Also it's not heating inside. I changed the heater but it's still the same...

any suggestion what to do?

Thanks
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would also be thermostat...

You can check that a thermostat is working correctly by putting it into a saucepan full of water (along with a thermometer), and heating the water - you should see the thermostat open when the water gets to the correct temperature. Then switch off the heat and check that it closes again as it cools.

Have you checked for any blockage or obstruction that might be stopping the thermostat from closing properly?

How long has the problem been going on for? Is it recent, or has it been happening all the time you have had the car? If so, it might be that a previous owner had modified the system to 'fix' (i.e. hide) some other problem...

Comment: Nick C, thanks for your answer! i tried with 4 thermostats i already have them i can give a test as you say.. 

Yes, i think also the thermostat looks like it's always opened and never close .. 

i have this car since 5 months but i have a friend that he have a same corsa , same engine and this happens with him also..